# Documentum - How to move content from Windows File System to NAS

Tags: migration, filesystems, documentum

We have a Documentum system where the content is stored on Windows File System
The data size is around 500GB.
We are planning to move from Windows File System to Cloud based NFS.

How can we move the existing content to the new location.

Will this work for the above volume

> 1. Create a New Storage Location in DA
> 2. Execute the Migrate Job to new
>      location

Are there any other ways that we can do this with less downtime.

Comment: I'm not the expert with system administration tasks but I'm quite sure that if you're using Documetnum built in job that (probably) you won't have any downtime, since Documentum is aware of the objects content location. Can you add more details to your question?